# SQL Server 2008: DateDiff Returning a negivate value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, coldfusion

In continuation of my Coldfusion and Student Certifications module series, I have come up with a bit of a problem.

When I return values for Coldfusion using the query below, I get negitave and postive dates.

What I need it to do is to return dates only greater then or equal to today, so if cprAdultExp is 2/27/2011, I need to return that value as 25, while if kidExp is 1/2/2011 I need it to return nothing.

Any thoughts?

SQL:

```
SELECT
p.firstName,
p.lastName,
m.profileID,
dateDiff(day,getDate(),m.cprAdultExp) as adultExp,
dateDiff(day,getDate(),m.cprInfantChildExp) as kidExp,
dateDiff(day,getDate(),m.cprFPRExp) as frpExp,
dateDiff(day,getDate(),m.aedExp) as aExp,
dateDiff(day,getDate(),m.firstAidExp) as aidExp,
dateDiff(day,getDate(),m.emtExp) as eExp,
dateDiff(day,getDate(),m.waterSafetyInstructionExp) as waterExpt,
dateDiff(day,getDate(),m.bloodPathogensExp) as bloodExp,
dateDiff(day,getDate(),m.oxygenAdminExp) as oxyExp,
dateDiff(day,getDate(),m.lifegaurdingExp) as lifeExp,
dateDiff(day,getDate(),m.wildernessResponderExp) as  wildExp,
m.certNotes
FROM 
pro_Profile p
LEFT JOIN mod_StudentCertifications m
ON
    m.profileID = p.profileID
WHERE
p.isDeleted='False'
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just include the condition in your `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
CASE WHEN m.cprAdultExp > getDate() THEN dateDiff(day,getDate(),m.cprAdultExp) ELSE NULL END as adultExp
```

Is that right?

Comment: Do I do a case for each element?